# submit html form with jstl rather than path = "" in input tags in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jstl

i have a edit page where i display information in

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="login.do" >
    <label for="msgTo" class="w80">To:</label> <input type="text"
                                id="msgTo" maxlength="15" size="20"
                                    value="${userLogin.userId}" />
```

in action class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin obj) {
```

Here, nothing of the form is coming in "UserLogin obj" object.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using spring-mvc tags consider using  form in input as follows

```
      <form:input type="text" path="msgTo" maxlength="15" size="20" 
value="${userLogin.userId}" />
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input

If you want to user @ModelAttribute combining with spring tags, consider read [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/)

Basically you need to use spring.tld in your form and create a bean that has bean properties equals to the name of the elements in the form.

Comment: its giving error saying missing required attribute 'path'

Comment: check the update in my answer, try to follow the tutorial in the link, there are several condition you must follow to complete this.

Comment: path shoudl be used instead of id, id is not used as you think in spring.tld, follow the links above with the doc, they will help you

Comment: Thanks. It did help.<form:input type="text"  id="msgTo" maxlength="15" size="20" 
          path= "userLogin.userId" /> I used path like this instead of ${ .... and it worked on form submit.